# Rasa init gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python, rasa, sqlite3-python

I created a virtual env using python3.9 . installed rasa using `pip3 install rasa` and tried `rasa init --noprompt` . I get error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_sqlite3’** I had installed sqlite in my debain 12 system and rebuilt python with sqlite dependency. also run `pip install db-sqlite3` inside venv. Still getting the same error. Please help. The complete output of rasa init can be found here:  https://pastebin.com/26VEBcDy

Ref: https://learning.rasa.com/installation/ubuntu/